# Magento customer collection order by firstname

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, query

My required result is customer collection sort by firstname (ascending and descending order)

```
The Query
--------
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('userid')->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')->addAttributeToSelect('profile_image')->addAttributeToSelect('specialist')->addAttributeToSelect('latitude')->addAttributeToSelect('free_consult')->addAttributeToSelect('longitude')->addAttributeToFilter('group_id',Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);
$collection->getSelect()->order("e.firstname ASC")

But its show an error "Unknown column 'e.firstname' in 'order clause'"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `$collection->getSelect()->order("e.firstname ASC")` use

```
$collection->addAttributeToSort('firstname', 'ASC')
```

And an off topic tip, you can add all the attributes you need to the select from one `addAttributeToSelect` statement like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('firstname', 'lastname', 'profile_image', 'specialist', 'latitude', 'free_consult', 'longitude'))
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### Edit:

`e` alias name indicate the `customer_entity" Customer Entity"`  table and as magento `Customer model is follow Eav Attribute structure`  then it does not save it in single flat table.

Better to use `addAttributeToSort()`

As customer model is **follow Eav Structure** that if you have trying sort using  `getSelect Query(->getSelect()->order("e.firstname ASC"))`

or using setOrder(fieldname',DESC) then it will risky becasue of multitple time join of below table s

1. `customer_entity`
2. `customer_entity_datetime`
3. `customer_entity_decimal`
4. `customer_entity_int`
5. `customer_entity_text`
6. `customer_entity_varchar`

etc

Above tables are **join several times basic of selet attribute** and sort **attribute in collection in different table alias name** `_getAttributeTableAlias()`.

Only you can do if `you have good & Solid knowledge about eav table of that Eav Model`.

If use `addAttributeToSort()` then magento is already do it logic on this function on

`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` class.

### Take a Look on function:

```
public function addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir = self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
{
    if (isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order($this->_getAttributeFieldName($attribute).' '.$dir);
        return $this;
    }
    if (isset($this->_staticFields[$attribute])) {
        $this->getSelect()->order("e.{$attribute} {$dir}");
        return $this;
    }
    if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])) {
        $attrInstance = $this->_joinAttributes[$attribute]['attribute'];
        $entityField = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute) . '.' . $attrInstance->getAttributeCode();
    } else {
        $attrInstance = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute);
        $entityField = 'e.' . $attribute;
    }

    if ($attrInstance) {
        if ($attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic()) {
            $orderExpr = $entityField;
        } else {
            $this->_addAttributeJoin($attribute, 'left');
            if (isset($this->_joinAttributes[$attribute])||isset($this->_joinFields[$attribute])) {
                $orderExpr = $attribute;
            } else {
                $orderExpr = $this->_getAttributeTableAlias($attribute).'.value';
            }
        }

        if (in_array($attrInstance->getFrontendClass(), $this->_castToIntMap)) {
            $orderExpr = Mage::getResourceHelper('eav')->getCastToIntExpression(
                $this->_prepareOrderExpression($orderExpr)
            );
        }

        $orderExpr .= ' ' . $dir;
        $this->getSelect()->order($orderExpr);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

**Note:**

I setOrder() really good idea whenever you have using `Non-Eav Model i,e Flat Collection(simple table model)`

Comment: do you having any other idea, i did but not getting the desired result

Comment: you can follow marius answer ...http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74298/magento-customer-collection-order-by-firstname/74306#74306 As customer is eav you use addAttributeToSort()

Comment: here i am unable to fetch the value firstname, lastname and rest of custom field value in  sales order column ..any help will be appreciated

Comment: here i am unable to fetch the value of firstname, last name and other created cutome in sales order grid coloumn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626259/how-can-fetch-data-from-shiiping-to-custom-field-in-sales-order-grid-page?noredirect=1#comment105418533_59626259 any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setOrder` instead of `order`

```
$collection->setOrder('firstname','DESC'); // for  descending order Use ASC for ascending
```

Comment: i follow with your way,but the expected result not get